# ReactJs bundle jsx files for multiple pages with jinja

Tags: javascript, jinja2, reactjs

I am working with React and trying to understand the best way to bundle the files for multiple pages into a single js file (script for js file in base jinja template.)

Everything works fine with the bundle but I am trying to understand how to handle the separate pages for the app entry point file.

Example entry file:

```
var React = require('react');
var Test = require('./test.jsx'); 
React.render(React.createElement(test.foo), document.getElementById('foo'));
React.render(React.createElement(test.bar), document.getElementById('bar'));
React.render(React.createElement(test.another), document.getElementById('another'));
```

So lets say one partial template I use foo and bar and another page uses another.
If I follow this pattern than I will get the console error of:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

since the templates do not contain all the elements rendered in the app.js entry script to the app.  What is the proper way to use a script across multiple pages without receiving an error like this?  What is the best way to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like document.getElementById is returning null, so use an if statement?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Webpack, if you haven't done that yet?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?